# Single sign on in two applications using windows identity foundation

Tags: c#

I have a two web application and a sts server. when user calls first web app it is redirected to sts server for validation. on validation the  user logs in to the 1st web app. In my 1st web app there is a button when clicked should open the 2nd web app without me asking for 
validation from sts server. Since I have added reference of sts in my second web app it is asking for validation again from sts server.

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks
Nilesh

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your STS does not retain the information about user being logged in. The STS itself has to use some authentication mechanism and ask users to log in only the FIRST time they visit the STS.

Comment: The issue was while installing WIF the wsfedaration module tag in web.config had issue due. i insatlled wif again and it worked...thanks for  your reply.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be a sync issue how are you verifying that the information is being authenticated and passed back, are the users perhaps not setup properly on one of the passthrough servers in regards to SSO authentication..? I would look at Session Variables and see if those are being kept or whiped.. just an idea..

also sounds like the users are not in that domain / authenticated group where you have setup SSO that's probably why it's popping up a user/login I've seen this before when I worked a Chase

Comment: We were authenticating agains AD in sts and after the user was authenticated he got access to the relying party..The issue was resolved after reinstalling the WIF.